# MS Word: how to enumerate pictures automatically?

Tags: ms-word

I'm writing a big document in MS Word 2013, and I have a lot of pictures which should have a description like `Fig. [section number].[figure number]. Random description`, e.g.

> Fig. 3.2. Screenshot of a window

`Figure number` should reset on each section.
So how do I do it automatically?
Right now I inserted "Quick Part" "Section" which has section number, but I don't know how to implement "figure number" part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ribbon → References → Captions → Insert caption`, in case anyone is interested.